# How to change POST request

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make post request in html in iframe, but after this post request user automatically redirect to request page.
I want to make just request, without redirect.

```
<form id="main-mailing-list" action="https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXX/sendMessage" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
  <input type="hidden" name="chat_id" value="-44947">
  <input tabindex="0" autocomplete="email" id="emailfield" data-validation="email" class="required email" name="text" type="email" placeholder="Your email address"> 
  <button id="submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button><br><br>
  <span id="thanks"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: If you only need to do the request, you must learn about [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can do it like this:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  //prevent from default behavior

    var email = $("#emailfield").val();
    var chat_id = $("#main-mailing-list [name='chat_id']").val();

    var data = {
        email: email,
        chat_id: chat_id
    };

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXX/sendMessage",
        data: data
    }).done(function(response){
       console.log(response)

    }).fail(function(error){
       console.error(error)
    });
});
```

Of course, if something will not work as expected it is very likely that headers are not set correctly. More info about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you for helping. But when I try with this code, page redirect to my website, but with parameters. So it looks like this: mywebsite.com/index.html?chat_id=-2447777&text=yaya%40ya.com

Comment: Then try changing event binding to this: `$("#main-mailing-list").on("submit", function(e){e.preventDefault(); ...the rest of your code...})`